# Calculating previous months from Date() duplicates a month

Tags: java, android, kotlin, date

I am trying to 12 previous months from today, but it displays

Date to start with - Mon May 30 22:57:30 GMT+01:00 2022

Months displayed are - these are the values in the `monthsArray`, Month March 2022 is displayed twice

```
April 2022
March 2022 (DISPLAYED TWICE)
March 2022 (DISPLAYED TWICE)
February 2022
January 2022
December 2021
November 2021
October 2021
September 2021
August 2021
July 2021
June 2021
```

This is the logic to display months

```
    val monthsArray: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    val date = Date()
    var i = 1
    while (i <= 12) {
        date.month = date.month - 1
        monthsArray.add(readableSpinnerItemDate(date.time))
        i++
    }
```

Could you please suggest what might be wrong here please

Comment: Sounds like a problem associated with having a date with the "day of month" being a value too big for February.  One of many, many reasons to never use `java.util.Date`.

Comment: What is wrong is first that [you are still using `Date`](https://programminghints.com/2017/05/still-using-java-util-date-dont/) in 2022. And what is still more wrong is that you are implicitly using its `getMonth` and `setMonth` methods that were deprecated 25 years ago because they work unreliably across time zones. Use `YearMonth` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: We don’t need the real explanation since we should under no circumstances use `Date`, so only out of theoretical curiosity: @LouisWasserman is right. You subtract months from May 30 to get April 30, then March 30, then February 30. February 30? Since there were only 28 days in February this year, `Date` regards this as equal to March 2. Therefore you get March a second time. (Next you get February 2, January 2 and so forth.) I repeat: Don’t use `Date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do what you are looking for.

```
val monthsArray = (0..11).map { LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(it.toLong()).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM yyyy")) }
```

Comment: Good answer, thanks. If this were for Android API level under 26, we would need [coreLibraryDesugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Since we don’t need the day of month, I would use `YearMonth` rather than `LocalDate`. The code is otherwise the same.